# Why the output is not same?

Tags: java, string, swap

The output of the fist `System.out.println()` is not same as the second `System.out.println()`
What may be the reason?

```
public class swapex{
    public static int var1, var2;

    public void badSwap(int var1, int var2){
        int temp = var1;
        this.var1 = var2;
        this.var2 = temp;
        System.out.println("var1 " + var1 + " var2 "+ var2);
    }

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        swapex sw= new swapex();
        sw.badSwap(10,20);
        System.out.println("var1 " + var1 + " var2 "+ var2);
    }
}
```

Comment: does this even compile? what is `this.var1`? `var1` is a **static** class variable, and a local parameter, not an instance member. Anyway, the play with `this.var1` is local and does nothing, since you print `val1`, not `this.var1`.

Comment: Kobi, this.var1 and var1 in main both refer to the static field.  This is definitely bad style.

Comment: Really? `this` works for a static field? it was `swapex.var1` when I studied Java...

Comment: Tip: Start class names with a capital letter. It's handy for distinguishing classes/methods/variables at a glance and it'll avoid you getting weird looks from other programmers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The first is outputting the parameter values, the second is outputting the static fields.

Let's look at all meaning of the relevant values.

```
public void badSwap(int var1, int var2){
```

`var1` and `var2` are arguments passed in to the method.

```
int temp = var1;
```

temp is set to the passed in var1.

```
this.var1 = var2;
```

The static field `var1` is set to the passed in `var2`.  This is poor style, because it is unnecessarily confusing.  If you have reason to use a static, write `swapex.var1`.

```
this.var2 = temp;
```

Again, the static field is being set.

```
System.out.println("var1 " + var1 + " var2 "+ var2);
```

The locals are being printed.

Back in main, the line:

```
System.out.println("var1 " + var1 + " var2 "+ var2);
```

resolves to the static fields because there are no stack variables with those names.  Again, this is also poor style.  You would use `swapex.var1` and `swapex.var2`.

So, the reason they print differently is that you first print the original unswapped arguments, then the swapped (inverse to the arguments) static fields.

Answer (score 1):

The variables you are setting in badswap are the local arguments, not the static members of swapex. Since the local scope takes precedence, the static members are unchanged

When you print the first time, you are printing the local arguments, the second time, you are printing the static members

to get the two to be the same, change the names of the arguments to badswap().

Comment: This is wrong.  badswap is setting the static variables, but printing the (unchanged) locals.   Then, later, the (swapped) statics are printed.

Answer (score 0):

```
In the method badswap the var1 and var2 that
```

gets printed is the local variables of the said method namely

badswap(**int var1, int var2**)

```
and not that of class variables
```

**public static int var1,var2**

and that is the cause for the difference.

Answer (score 0):

`static` fields are relative to a class. The `this` keyword is usually used to distinguish between an identically-named local variable and a class variable. It is advised to avoid using this to refer to static fields as this unnecessary but the compiler appears to accept it.

Additionally, var1 and var2 only exist within the scope of your badSwap() method. This is why you're getting a different output. The sysout within the method is displaying paramater values whereas the sysout in the main is displaying the values of class variables.